# How can I estimate the sum of coefficients

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding, sum

I am trying to estimate the cumulative effect. When I have an ols regression with many dummies as explanatory variables, can I sum the coefficients to find the cumulative effect?

If yes, how do I find the level of significance of the sum? For example I would like to check the effect of central banks announcements in corporate bonds. So every day that there was an announcement is a dummy equal to 1 on that day and 0 on the others.

Comment: The term to google is "contrasts"; your contrast will be given by the vector of 1's.

Comment: Could you explain what a "cumulative effect" might be?  Although you describe an OLS regression, the situation sounds more like a time series setting.

Comment: Every announcement has an effect , for example a reduction of 16bp . can i estimate the effect of all the announcements? yes it is time series. is it wrong using an OLS ?

Comment: Could you expand on the context? What does your data represent in the real world? What is your research goal?